# How to create strings in C# which contain "

Tags: c#, .net, string

How can I create a string in C# which contains: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"

Comment: holy crap there's an echo in here....

Answer (score 7):

```
string s = "AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet\"";
```

Comment: Or, `string s = @"AT+CGDCONT=1,""IP"",""internet""";`

Answer (score 3):

try

```
string item1 = @"AT+CGDCONT=1,""IP"",""internet""";
```

or

```
string item2 = "AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet\"";
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a string literal:

```
@"AT+CGDCONT=1,""IP"",""internet"""
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply escape the double quotes using the escape character `\`:

```
string foo = "AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet\"";
```

This blog will give you [a list of available escape sequences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use `\` to escape characters in a C# string, so in your case:

```
var myString = "AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet\"";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put a \ before the " like so:

```
string s = "AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet\"";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string myString = "AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet\""
```

Here is a [list of all character escapes you can use](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx).